# Wpf - Grid using row and column definition - How to ignore columns for some rows

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, grid-layout, groupbox

I'm trying to use the grid row / column definitions in my wpf application. At the moment, I need to implement a list view inside a GroupBox. Here I need to ignore the column definitions i set in the top in the view.

**Row and column definitions:**

```
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="260" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="250" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="180" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="180" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

Here you see I have a rowDefinition with a height of 260. This should contain my list view. The problem is that it's inside the columns I have made and therefore it won't take all space. Is there somehow a setting so that this row will ignore the columns I have set? I still want the columns to be used for the other rows.

Here you see a picture of how it looks:

[image]

Hope someone can help, good day.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just use attached property `Grid.ColumnSpan` :

```
<ListView Grid.ColumnSpan="6"/>
```

It will extend your `ListView` for 6 columns.

**Simple advice about your UI:**

I suggest you to create you resizable XAML, not static. I mean it is not good:

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="260" />
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="250" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="180" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="180" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

However, it is better:

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="3*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

It gives resizable UI(XAML) at any display.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Will try this out asap!

Answer (score 1):

You can set `Grid.ColumnSpan="6"` on your listview. It will expand in the row.

```
<ListView Grid.ColumnSpan="6"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

depends on how you want to display the listview.

you can add another grid, just to be safe, that you will want to add something later on that row.

```
<Grid grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="6">
  <ListView> </ListView>
</Grid>
```